# Why 'raise EXCEPTION from CAUSE', not 'raise (EXCEPTION from CAUSE)'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Let me elaborate on the mildly cryptic question title.

In Python 3 we've got neat exception chaining feature, that lets you add more context to exceptions in the process of their propagation.

Recently, I wanted to attach extra exception information to the exception, but without throwing it straightaway. The code was doing some defensive processing in generator, so I wanted to yield it instead, so I tried something like:

```py
def gen():
   for row in csv_file:
       try:
          yield parse(row)
       except Exception as e:
          yield RuntimeError(f"Bad row: {row}") from e
```

To my disappointment, that didn't work! Turned out that `raise EXCEPTION from CAUSE` is a compound operator as [PEP-3134](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/#explicit-exception-chaining) explains.

To get around this in my code, I set `__cause__ = e` manually and carried on. However, it still bothered me why it was implemented that way.

**Imagine** instead we had an operator `from` with the following syntax: `EXCEPTION from CAUSE`, doing exactly what `raise .. from ..` is doing, except throwing, and returning new `Exception` instead. That way:

- it's **compatible**, you can still use `raise .. from ..` syntax (now internally it'd be parsed as `raise (.. from ..)`)
- it would make everything more **composable**, allowing to attach cause without necessarily throwing (in particular my usecase). I can that it's a bit unusual use of exceptions though.
- presumably, that would also **make implementation simpler**, since you'd not need to modify and clash exiting primitive (simple `raise` operator). I see it as a main argument for my 'alternative form' of the operator from the perspective of Python language developer.

I've gone through PEP/googled but hasn't really found any rationale. I experimented to check if there is something else apart from `__cause__` being set, but it doesn't seem so. I'm attaching bits of code that I used to check that:

```py
def failing():
    raise RuntimeError("function failed!")


def cause_from():
    try:
        failing()
    except Exception as e:
        raise RuntimeError("extra info") from e

def cause_manual():
    try:
        failing()
    except Exception as e:
        ee = RuntimeError("extra info")
        ee.__cause__ = e
        raise ee
```

It results in the same traceback:

```
$ python3 -c 'import exc; exc.cause_from()'                                                                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/exc.py", line 7, in cause_from
    failing()
  File "/tmp/exc.py", line 2, in failing
    raise RuntimeError("function failed!")
RuntimeError: function failed!

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/exc.py", line 9, in cause_from
    raise RuntimeError("extra info") from e
RuntimeError: extra info
```

```
$ python3 -c 'import exc; exc.cause_manual()'                                                                                                                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/exc.py", line 13, in cause_manual
    failing()
  File "/tmp/exc.py", line 2, in failing
    raise RuntimeError("function failed!")
RuntimeError: function failed!

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/exc.py", line 17, in cause_manual
    raise ee
RuntimeError: extra info
```

The only difference in traceback is the line where exception was thrown (`raise RuntimeError("extra info") from e` vs `raise ee`). The `cause_from` version looks somewhat more readable.

So it's the only reason I see for that choice of syntax structure, I wonder if it's also the intended motivation? Is it possible that I miss some subtle effect of `raise .. from ..` as a compound operator?

Comment: Probably because the developers didn't think anyone would go around returning it yielding exceptions. That's not what they're for. They don't even make for a good flag value in your case. Look at how futures are done in multi-threading for an example of what I mean.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for your comment, I clarified a bit that my main question is not about allowing my (unconventional, I agree) usecase, but about the ease of implementing it from Python developer's perspective.

Comment: See [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design)

Comment: @MadPhysicist regarding "That's not what they're for": yep, I used futures, so I can see what you mean. However I find yielding exceptions very convenient on practice since they let me write compact uncluttered code and play well with `mypy` (as opposed to checking `if future.is_error()`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the link, I had no idea it was frowned upon! The problem is: the question might have a practical answer if someone demonstrates that it's not merely a design choice but that there is an actual difference (hence, my misinterpretation of the way operator works)?

Comment: What is the point of yielding exceptions? If you yield them, you have to check them like `isinstance(something, Exception)`. It is not the right way of handling exceptions. They must be caught in `except` clause. To do it you have to `raise` them first.

Comment: @sanyash there is no 'right' way of handling exceptions it's a hard open problem. There are languages than don't have them at all and rely on return values (e.g. rust/go), some use mixed error handling models (e.g. c++). Of course, I agree that generally exceptions have to be thrown; in my particular case I have a generator so if I throw it would stop iterating. Generally it's good to crash ASAP, but sometimes you want to be defensive (e.g. you want to present the error to user or log it). In that case it's inevitable to return/yield _something_ (and yes, sadly do isinstance/ predicate checks)

Comment: @karlicoss Here's a demo of how you can make what you want to accomplish happen: https://repl.it/@blhsing/SecretTraumaticDisplaymanager